# Solana/Anchor error: (yanked dependencies) Failed to obtain package metadata: `cargo metadata` exited with an error: Updating crates.io index

Tags: rust, smartcontracts, rust-cargo, solana, anchor-solana

I just set up a new anchor project yesterday, every command runs smoothly.

Today I installed a new anchor project. I run `anchor test` to see if the project is set up correctly. I am getting this error:

```
Failed to obtain package metadata: `cargo metadata` exited with an error:     Updating crates.io index
error: failed to select a version for the requirement `anchor-lang = "^0.23.0"`
candidate versions found which didn't match: 0.24.2
location searched: crates.io index
required by package `myAnchorProject v0.1.0 (.../programs/myAnchorProject)`
```

It is not clear what candidate versions mean. I deleted node_modules and install it with `"@project-serum/anchor": "^0.24.2"`, still same error.

I clear the `lib.rs` and testing file to see something different, but it still gives the same error.

executing `cargo update` is giving same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the problem with dependency in your `package.json` is due to the use of yanked rust crate `anchor-lang`

all the other version the `0.24.2` have been yanked so you can't build any cargo project which has yanked dependeny.

refer here https://crates.io/crates/anchor-lang/versions

what you need to do get it working is
go to `<your-project-root>/programs/myAnchorProject/cargo.toml`.
I'm assuming your program name is `myAnchorProject` or replace it with your program name.

your current cargo.toml must look something like

```
...
<other content goes here>
...

[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "^0.23.0"
```

you need to upgrade the anchor-lang version to `0.24.2` or any other version if available which is not yanked.

so your final cargo.toml should look like

```
...
<other content goes here>
...

[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "^0.24.2"
```

Comment: Arjun, thank you it is resolved. what is yanked Dependency. i googled but could not find anything

Comment: @Yilmaz when a rust crate is yanked it literally mean it's removed from the index and now it can't be pulled from crate index.
https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-yank.html